# Create iptables Rule for Specific URL on Specific Machine?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, iptables

I have an existing home network with DNS (via BIND) and DHCP running on an Raspberry Pi.  I would like to develop an `iptables` rule that restricts a single device to a single URL.

1. For device `kid.laptop.lan` (MAC or IP works too)
2. Drop all traffic on `tcp 80`
3. Except `kidsafe.website.com`

I still need to be able to SSH into the device (which is running Ubuntu 17.10).  If there's an easier method (e.g. DansGuardian), I'm open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this depending on how locked down you want to make it. The easiest way would be to block only traffic on port 80 and 443 except to a known IP, which leaves it possible for a motivated person to leak/exfiltrate data, but this is far beyond your average kids abity.  You can do this by IP with commands like

```
iptables -I -s kids.ip -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -I -s kids.ip -d dest.ip.to.allow -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I -s kids.ip -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
iptables -I -s kids.ip -d dest.ip.to.allow -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Note that order is important, as rules are inserted at top of table, so the last rule is matched first.

You will need to ensure the device uses a static IP (kids.ip) for this to work.  It does not affect mail, DNS or other non-web traffic.